# Azure DevOps: CI Pipeline executing after merge

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I have implemented a pipeline that will build and test the application once a Pull Request have been created. It works fine but it will run again once the PR is merged, and I only want it to run in the creation of a PR.

The Yaml fine goes like:

```
trigger:
- development

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk 3.1.000'
  inputs:
    version: 3.1.x
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build the application'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: 'example.csproj'
    configuration: 'Release'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Run unit tests'
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    projects: 'example.csproj'
    configuration: 'Release'
```

Comment: If this is a seperate Pipeline exclusive vor PR, add the build to branch policy, and remove the ```trigger``` in the pipeline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[kraego is right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69012580/azure-devops-ci-pipeline-executing-after-merge#comment121969707_69012580).

You will have to **remove** the `trigger` section within your pipeline and configure a build validation branch policy for that build.

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203#build-validation).